# Sample for publish/subscribe with Azure Cosmos DB in Java

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-java-sdk, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I need a pub/sub event message system with Azure Cosmos DB. I use Azure Cosmos DB Java SDK v4.

I try with a ChangeFeedProcessor based on this sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-java-sql-api-samples/blob/main/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/examples/changefeed/SampleChangeFeedProcessor.java but it does not work like expected.

My problems:

- The feed collection/container grow continue. How can I delete an event after all active nodes have receive the event?
- The delay for the events seems relative large. Around a minute.
- Only one node receive the events. This seems interesting for load balancing but this is not my use case.

Comment: Why is Pub/Subs required in Change feed? Moreover, you need  multiple Processors as your subscribers

Comment: I does not understand the question. I need a pub/sub that send an event to all nodes/hosts that are connected. For example a configuration change. I does not need a change feed. The ChangeFeedProcessor is an API that I have try because it was suggested in some comments and look like a solution.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you expecting data to be deleted from the container after reading via Change Feed?

Comment: Yes, after an event is pushed to all nodes there is no meaning for the event anymore. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With version 4.12.0 of the Java SDK the follow code snipped works for me. But it use beta code from the driver. It can change in the future.

```
private static final String                CHANNEL = "events";

private CosmosContainer                    collection;

private boolean                            stopped;

void start( String clientID ) {
    CosmosContainerProperties props = new CosmosContainerProperties( CHANNEL, "/type" );
    // delete all events after 60 seconds. All nodes should receive it in the meantime.
    props.setDefaultTimeToLiveInSeconds( 60 );
    collection = getOrCreateContainer( props );
    Thread thread = new Thread( () -> {
        String[] continuation = new String[1];
        try {
            while( !stopped ) {
                // sample code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/src/test/java/com/azure/cosmos/CosmosContainerChangeFeedTest.java
                CosmosChangeFeedRequestOptions options = continuation[0] == null ? //
                CosmosChangeFeedRequestOptions.createForProcessingFromNow( FeedRange.forFullRange() ) : // initial value
                CosmosChangeFeedRequestOptions.createForProcessingFromContinuation( continuation[0] ); // continue value
                Iterator<EventPOJO> it = collection //
                                .queryChangeFeed( options, EventPOJO.class ) //
                                .handle( ( response ) -> continuation[0] = response.getContinuationToken() ) //
                                .iterator();
                while( it.hasNext() ) {
                    EventPOJO event = it.next();
                    if( event.client != clientID ) {
                        // filter the own events
                        onMessage( event );
                    }
                }
                // poll interval
                Thread.sleep( 1000 );
            }
        } catch( Throwable th ) {
            if( !stopped ) {
                PersistenceLogger.LOGGER.error( th );
            }
        }
    }, CHANNEL );
    thread.setDaemon( true );
    thread.start();
}

<T> void send( T event, String clientID ) {
    EventPOJO evt = new EventPOJO();
    evt.id = ...
    evt.client = clientID;
    evt.type = event.getClass().getName();
    evt.message = ...

    collection.createItem( evt );
}
```